# Load h5 file with keras in Foundry code repository

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

im trying to load a h5 file into Keras inside a foundry code repository. Here is my code:

```
import os
import pkg_resources
from keras.models import load_model

def m_path(model_id):
    MODEL_PATH = pkg_resources.resource_filename('myproject', 'models/')
    return os.path.join(MODEL_PATH, f'lstm_{model_id}.h5')

model_path_gnd = m_path('V1')
model_gnd = load_model(model_path_gnd)
```

Im getting the follwing error:

```
[module version: 1.1004.0]

ImportError: Filepath looks like a hdf5 file but h5pyis not available. filepath=/app/work-dir/environment/SYMLINKS/site-packages/myproject/models/lstm_gnd.h5

File "/app/work-dir/environment/SYMLINKS/site-packages/keras/src/saving/legacy/save.py", line 244, in load_model raise ImportError( ImportError: Filepath looks like a hdf5 file but h5pyis not available. filepath=/app/work-dir/environment/SYMLINKS/site-packages/myproject/models/lstm_gnd.h5
```

i have imported the keras and h5py in the yaml file. Does anyone had a similar problem or know the issue?

Thanks and BR

Tellos

i added and removed the h5py in the yaml

Comment: It looks like you're trying to load a file from the repository itself. The usual pattern is to upload the raw file to a dataset and then load from the dataset. Is this for a compute module or are you trying to run inference with the model in a Python transform?

Comment: Yes, i load the file directly from the repo. What is the advantage of putting the file into a foundry dataset first? 
It should be a library which applies a model to new data.

Comment: This [documentation](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/integrate-models/model-asset-files/) shows the suggested path for using models from files in Foundry. That produces a model asset, which you can use in a transform to apply that model to new data or host the model behind a live endpoint to use from within Foundry applications - this also benefits from significantly easier upgrades as you can just change the model files in place and republish your model asset.